# Extracting data from html in bash script

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I want to get the data (line, destination, time and pos) displayed at this 
[subway schedule](http://mon.ruter.no/SisMonitor/Refresh?stopid=3010370&computerid=acba4167-b79f-4f8f-98a6-55340b1cddb3&isOnLeftSide=true&blocks=&rows=6&test=&stopPoint=) page.

The code I wrote for now is :

```
#!/bin/bash
curl "http://mon.ruter.no/SisMonitor/Refresh?stopid=3010370&computerid=acba4167-b79f-4f8f-98a6-55340b1cddb3&isOnLeftSide=true&blocks=&rows=6&test=&stopPoint=">ruter.html
awk -F "</*td>|</*tr>" '/<\/*t[rd]>.*[A-Z][0-9]/ {print $3, $5, $8, $10 }' ruter.html
```

Comment: I did change a little on this code on awk part,as:
awk -F "</*td>|</*tr>" '/<\/*t[rd]>.*/ {print $1, $2, $4, $5 }' ruter1.html                 and worked out some result like:   Bergkrystallen via Majorstuen
  Ringen via Storo            
 1 min
 <td class="center">2            ........(so on the 6 group)  seems still messy and with html tags.
   But I know little about awk, I can't improve it.   So I would rather user a loop or something make it easier to understand.

Comment: Another quetion is, that I also want to print only the one row(first subway time) which the Pro=1 or Pro=2 (according to the flag with the command line,for example if I give the command ./subway.sh -W, it give the latest subway time of platform1 or if I give the command  ./subway.sh -E , it give the latest subway time of platform2)

Answer (score 3):

[Don't use regular expressions for this at all.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) Convert from HTML to XML, and use XPath -- a query language that works on document semantics, as opposed to mere text-matching:

```
url="http://mon.ruter.no/SisMonitor/Refresh?stopid=3010370&computerid=acba4167-b79f-4f8f-98a6-55340b1cddb3&isOnLeftSide=true&blocks=&rows=6&test=&stopPoint="

curl "$url" | \
  tidy -asxml -n -c -b -q --show-warnings no | \
  xmlstarlet sel -N h=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml \
    -t -m '//h:tr[h:td]' \
    -v ./h:td[1] -o $'\t' \
    -v ./h:td[2] -o $'\t' \
    -v ./h:td[4] -o $'\t' \
    -v ./h:td[5] -n | \
  column -s $'\t' -t
```

For the given input HTML, as of today, the output is:

```
5  Vestli via Majorstuen          nå      1
4  Vestli via Storo               2 min   2
5  Ringen via Majorstuen          4 min   1
5  Sognsvann                      7 min   2
4  Bergkrystallen via Majorstuen  10 min  1
5  Ringen via Storo               12 min  2
```

---

The tools used here are:

- [HTML Tidy](http://www.html-tidy.org/) (for converting messy HTML into compliant XHTML)
- [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html) (for performing XPath queries)
- [column](http://linux.die.net/man/1/column) (for formatting the output into aligned columns)

Note also that `$'\t'` syntax requires that the shell in use *really be bash* (not `/bin/sh`).

Comment: Thank you so much! But I tried as u write, didn't get the result... should I also install something? Another trouble is, that I need to print only the one row(latest one) which the Pro=1 or Pro=2 (according to the flag with the command line,for example if I give the command ./subway.sh -W or ./subway.sh -E)

Comment: You do need tidy and xmlstarlet installed -- if either isn't, there should be a self-explanatory error on stderr. As for filtering for a specific platform, you can make it `-m "//h:tr[h:td[5] = '1']"` or `'2'` as appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

With `links`:

```
links -dump 'http://mon.ruter.no/SisMonitor/Refresh?stopid=3010370&computerid=acba4167-b79f-4f8f-98a6-55340b1cddb3&isOnLeftSide=true&blocks=&rows=6&test=&stopPoint='
```

Output:

```
   Linje Destinasjon                     Tid    Pos 
   Line  Destination                     Time   Pos 
   4     Vestli via Storo                3 min  2   
   5     Vestli via Majorstuen           3 min  1   
   5     Ringen via Majorstuen           5 min  1   
   5     Sognsvann                       11 min 2   
   4     Bergkrystallen via Majorstuen   12 min 1   
   5     Ringen via Storo                13 min 2
```

Comment: Niiiice. This is a tool I'd forgotten about.

Comment: or `lynx -dump <URL>`.

Comment: Isn't links much more actively maintained? My impression of lynx was that it was basically a dead project more than a decade ago.

Comment: That is possible.

Comment: No the last update was on 2016/04/26. Did you know that lynx urine is a cure against kidney stone?

Comment: Thank you very much! But is there only this one sentence? I tried the same with u, but not working...